# Install Photoshop in ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, windows, wine, photoshop

I have ubuntu 20.04 machine.I want to install photoshop,is it possible to install .I dont want to dual boot just because of it.

Comment: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-adobe-photoshop-linux/

Comment: it is possbile also you can see which versions run better using wine in https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?iId=17&sClass=application

Comment: Alternatively, see if the free and open source alternative GIMP works for you. `sudo apt install gimp`. Homepage: http://gimp.org

Comment: it really helped thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can install it with `playonlinux`

1. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
2. `wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key`
3. `sudo apt-key add winehq.key`
4. `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'`
5. `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`
6. `sudo apt install playonlinux`
7. Open the `playonlinux`
8. Click on the install button
9. Click on the graphic button --> click on photoshop version you want --> then click on `install`
10. Go to browse and click on `Set-up.exe`